# Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet' in DhtmlGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml, dhtmlx

I'm using DhtmlxGrid in jsp to get data and display data on popup, I can run good on IE, but on Chrome and Firefox can not

this is my JS file(dhtmlxgrid.js):

```
  ...
  document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(prefs[i]+(" {"+this.ssModifier[i]+" };"), document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length);}};this.setColumnColor=function(clr){this.columnColor=clr.split(this.delim)
  ...
```

When I load data, it not display and I see that it happen a bug on console browser following as:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the rule '#qlist1_grid table.hdr td {text-align:center; };'.
at window.(anonymous function).setStyle (http://localhost:8080/QMTM_DEMO/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js:282:26)
at qlist1_init_qlist_grid (http://localhost:8080/project/tman/exam/exam_make_write.jsp?id_exam=E170926092443OV:86:15)
at option_init (http://localhost:8080/project/tman/exam/exam_make_write.jsp?id_exam=E170926092443OV:71:3)
at onload (http://localhost:8080/project/tman/exam/exam_make_write.jsp?id_exam=E170926092443OV:110:47)
```

because it can not load data, some functions of javascript is not active

How to fix this error ?